# Wrong validation position when I try to restore browser

Tags: php, javascript, html

I almost done my page with two required login boxes for clients, I use validation for those input box. I use HTML5, JavaScript and CSS. I am little upset when error message displayed on wrong place when I try to restore the browser.

I want to ask if there has any solution to make the validation message (error message) always next to input box (such as auto position)? so when we restore the browser, the error message always stay in it's position (next to input box) not separate as on the pics above!

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/wb.validation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#Form1").submit(function(event)
   {
      var isValid = $.validate.form(this);
      return isValid;
   });
   $("#phone").validate(
   {
      required: true,
      type: 'custom',
      param: /$myregexvalidation/, 
      color_text: '#000000',
      color_hint: '#00FF00',
      color_error: '#FF0000',
      color_border: '#808080',
      nohint: true,
      font_family: 'Arial',
      font_size: '13px',
      position: 'centerright',
      offsetx: 0,
      offsety: 0,
      bubble_class: 'bubbleleft',
      effect: 'fade',
      error_text: 'Introduza um número de telemóvel válido!'
   });
   $("#email").validate(
   {
      required: true,
      type: 'custom',
      param: /$myregexvalidation/,
      color_text: '#000000',
      color_hint: '#00FF00',
      color_error: '#FF0000',
      color_border: '#808080',
      nohint: true,
      font_family: 'Arial',
      font_size: '13px',
      position: 'centerright',
      offsetx: 0,
      offsety: 0,
      bubble_class: 'bubbleleft',
      effect: 'fade',
      error_text: 'Por favor introduz um email válido!'
   });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="save.php" target="_self" id="Form1">
    <div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:15px;width:70px;height:34px;z-index:0;text-align:left;"> <span style="color:#F5FFFA;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Telemóvel</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="phone" style="position:absolute;left:82px;top:10px;width:155px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:1;" name="phone" value="" maxlength="8" placeholder="">
    <div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:55px;width:62px;height:17px;z-index:2;text-align:left;"> <span style="color:#F5FFFA;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">E-mail</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="email" style="position:absolute;left:82px;top:51px;width:155px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:3;" name="email" value="" maxlength="50" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Entrar" style="position:absolute;left:176px;top:93px;width:67px;height:32px;z-index:4;">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "restore the browser"?

Comment: http://www.courses-online.co.uk/getimage.php?Key=1&File=Objects/08000012.png&width=157&height=108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add an empty span for your error message right to the input fields. And then use js to add the error to the span. But you have to clear it if it is right. I have also reformatted your HTML a bit, that each form input/label/error message is being wrapped in one div.

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="save.php" target="_self" id="Form1">
    <div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:15px;width:70px;height:34px;z-index:0;text-align:left;">
        <span style="color:#F5FFFA;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Telemóvel</span>
        <input type="text" id="phone" style="position:absolute;left:82px;top:10px;width:155px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:1;" name="phone" value="" maxlength="8" placeholder="">
        <span id="errorPhone" class="error">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>

    <div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:55px;width:62px;height:17px;z-index:2;text-align:left;">
        <span style="color:#F5FFFA;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">E-mail</span>
        <input type="text" id="email" style="position:absolute;left:82px;top:51px;width:155px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:3;" name="email" value="" maxlength="50" placeholder="">
        <span id="errorEmail" class="error">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Entrar" style="position:absolute;left:176px;top:93px;width:67px;height:32px;z-index:4;">
</form>
```

And then in js, in the validate()-method,

```
/* this text will appear in span with id errorPhone */
$("#errorPhone").text('Introduza um número de telemóvel válido!');

/* this in errorEmail */
$("#errorEmail").text('Por favor introduz um email válido!');
```

If you want to clear it, you have simply to use '' in the .text() method. (Just do this before the validate()-method.

And if possible, please try to style your browser by using a stylesheet from .css file. This will not only improve the HTML format, but also make styling more efficient. ([here is a small tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php))